# Append string with view name

Tags: ios, swift

I have similar type of buttons, the only difference they have is the integer appended at the end of name.

Code snippet:

```
radioButtonController1 = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: radioBtn1,radiobtn2)
radioButtonController1!.delegate = self
radioButtonController1!.shouldLetDeSelect = false

radioButtonController2 = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: radioBtn3,radioBtn4)
radioButtonController2!.delegate = self
radioButtonController2!.shouldLetDeSelect = false

radioButtonController3 = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: radioBtn5,radioBtn6,radioBtn7)
radioButtonController3!.delegate = self
radioButtonController3!.shouldLetDeSelect = false

radioButtonController4 = SSRadioButtonsController(buttons: radioBtn8,radioBtn9)
radioButtonController4!.delegate = self
radioButtonController4!.shouldLetDeSelect = false
```

Now, I want to do this in a single loop, to reduce the code. Is there any way, I can do it in a loop? Like create a variable and addd an integer at the end, something like below:

```
for index in 1...11 {
    radioButtonController = radioButtonController.append("\(index)")
}
```

Above code throws a conversion error.

Comment: You could use an array of `SSRadioButtonsController`.

Comment: something like this @Code ?  `var radioButtonController: [SSRadioButtonsController] = []`

Comment: But that does not answer my question about appending in integer at the end of view name

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is any way to do what what you want the way your doing it.

You could just place all the radio buttons into an array then use the array index to find the button you want when you're enumerating through.